# Simulate Operation with Unrevealed Key Protocol Kathmandu

Tags: protocol, reveal, dry-run

I'm trying to check my system works fine with the new Kathmandu protocol, so I'm testing some features with the `kathmandunet`.
When I'm trying to simulate an operation (using `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/simulate_operation`), I'm getting an `proto.014-PtKathma.contract.unrevealed_key error` (A reveal operation was not yet sent from my address).
This behaviour didn't seem to occur with previous protocols (transaction simulation did not seem to relate to whether the public key is revealed), but I couldn't find anything is the documentation about this change.

Does anyone know if this change was indeed introduced in protocol Kathmandu and maybe direct me to a relevant documentation?

Comment: You mean that it was possible to `/simulate_operation` where the source has empty balance befer K, but not possible anymore on `kathmandunet`? If yes, there were some changes regarding simulation which probably explain this new behaviour.

Comment: Yes, sounds like I'm referring to these changes in the simulation.
Do you know where I can find any documentation about these changes?
I'd like to check out if any of these has any additional effect I'm unaware of